# How to use custom button call Editor template and passing value to popup

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm use kendo ui grid popup and using code

```
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("tax_manage")
```

I and use

```
columns.Command(command => command.Custom("ViewData").Text("ViewData")).Width(60).Title("ViewData");
```

How to do this?
In my kendo grid Custom button to call "tax_manage" in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/tax_manage`
and show template inner popup with Javascript and when I click Custom Button I need to pass value to popup, such as a string (e.g.: this was called by Custom Button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can send the parameter via the corresponding table row. To open the popup, you can use grid's `editRow` method:

```
columns.Command(command => command.Custom("ViewData").Text("ViewData").Click("cmdClick"))
...
.Events(events => events.Edit("gridEdit"))
```

```js
function cmdClick(e) {
    var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the corresponding table row
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(tr); // You may want to use the corresponding data item ...
    tr.data("message") = "This was called by Custom Button";
    grid.editRow(tr);
}
function gridEdit(e) {
    var dataItem = e.model;
    var tr = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']");
    var message = tr.data("message");
    ... // do something with the message. 
}
```